# NVIDIA driver is no longer working with new kernel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

The nvidia-driver-515-open (proprietary, tested) is no longer working with my GeForce RTX 3080 Lite Hash Rate. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. Everything was fine until an update last week. The 5.15.0-50-generic produces regular screen blanks. The nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary) boots to a blank screen only.

Under 5.15.0-48-generic with nvidia-driver-515-open (proprietary, tested) the system is more stable but very slow.

These outputs were created under under 5.15.0-48-generic as 5.15.0-48-generic is not stable enough.

Results of `modinfo /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko | grep ^version` :

```
modinfo: ERROR: Module /usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko not found.
```

Results of `nvidia-settings` :

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

(nvidia-settings:18455): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 20:38:47.756: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:18455): CRITICAL **: 20:38:47.762: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible.
       This file should have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

** Message: 20:38:47.894: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 20:38:47.894: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

Results of `sudo lshw -C display` :

```
  *-display UNGEFORDERT     
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080 Lite Hash Rate]
       Hersteller: NVIDIA Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
       Version: a1
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       Konfiguration: latency=0
       Ressourcen: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:440-43f memory:a1000000-a1ffffff memory:4000000000-43ffffffff memory:4400000000-4401ffffff ioport:5000(Größe=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       Produkt: EFI VGA
       Physische ID: 2
       Logischer Name: /dev/fb0
       Fähigkeiten: fb
       Konfiguration: depth=32 resolution=3840,2160
```

Please let me know if further information is needed as I'm no expert.

---

`apt-term.log`:

```
Log started: 2022-10-14  10:37:34
(Lese Datenbank ... 
(Lese Datenbank ... 5%
(Lese Datenbank ... 10%
(Lese Datenbank ... 15%
(Lese Datenbank ... 20%
(Lese Datenbank ... 25%
(Lese Datenbank ... 30%
(Lese Datenbank ... 35%
(Lese Datenbank ... 40%
(Lese Datenbank ... 45%
(Lese Datenbank ... 50%
(Lese Datenbank ... 55%
(Lese Datenbank ... 60%
(Lese Datenbank ... 65%
(Lese Datenbank ... 70%
(Lese Datenbank ... 75%
(Lese Datenbank ... 80%
(Lese Datenbank ... 85%
(Lese Datenbank ... 90%
(Lese Datenbank ... 95%
(Lese Datenbank ... 100%
(Lese Datenbank ... 319810 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Entfernen von linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-48-generic (5.15.0-48.54) ...
linux-image-nvidia-5.15.0-48-generic: removing .ko files
(Lese Datenbank ... 
(Lese Datenbank ... 5%
(Lese Datenbank ... 10%
(Lese Datenbank ... 15%
(Lese Datenbank ... 20%
(Lese Datenbank ... 25%
(Lese Datenbank ... 30%
(Lese Datenbank ... 35%
(Lese Datenbank ... 40%
(Lese Datenbank ... 45%
(Lese Datenbank ... 50%
(Lese Datenbank ... 55%
(Lese Datenbank ... 60%
(Lese Datenbank ... 65%
(Lese Datenbank ... 70%
(Lese Datenbank ... 75%
(Lese Datenbank ... 80%
(Lese Datenbank ... 85%
(Lese Datenbank ... 90%
(Lese Datenbank ... 95%
(Lese Datenbank ... 100%
(Lese Datenbank ... 319807 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../00-nvidia-driver-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von nvidia-driver-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../01-libnvidia-extra-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../02-libnvidia-common-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-common-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../03-libnvidia-gl-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
De-konfigurieren von libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), um libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) konfigurieren zu können ...
dpkg-query: Kein Paket gefunden, das auf libnvidia-gl-510 passt
Entpacken von libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../04-libnvidia-gl-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
dpkg-query: Kein Paket gefunden, das auf libnvidia-gl-510 passt
Entpacken von libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../05-nvidia-dkms-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Entpacken von nvidia-dkms-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../06-nvidia-kernel-source-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von nvidia-kernel-source-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../07-linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04_5.15.0-50.56+1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04 (5.15.0-50.56+1) über (5.15.0-50.56) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../08-linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-50-generic_5.15.0-50.56+1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56+1) über (5.15.0-50.56) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../09-linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-50-generic_5.15.0-50.56+1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56+1) über (5.15.0-50.56) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../10-linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-50-generic_5.15.0-50.56+1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56+1) über (5.15.0-50.56) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../11-nvidia-kernel-common-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von nvidia-kernel-common-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../12-libnvidia-decode-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
De-konfigurieren von libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), um libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) konfigurieren zu können ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../13-libnvidia-decode-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../14-libnvidia-compute-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
De-konfigurieren von libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), um libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) konfigurieren zu können ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../15-libnvidia-compute-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../16-nvidia-compute-utils-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von nvidia-compute-utils-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../17-libnvidia-encode-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
De-konfigurieren von libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), um libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) konfigurieren zu können ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../18-libnvidia-encode-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../19-nvidia-utils-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von nvidia-utils-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../20-libnvidia-fbc1-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
De-konfigurieren von libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), um libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) konfigurieren zu können ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../21-libnvidia-fbc1-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../22-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../23-libnvidia-cfg1-515_515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) über (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-kernel-common-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
nvidia-kernel-source-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56+1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-utils-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-common-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-dkms-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-515.76 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-50-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-50-generic
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-50-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-50-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-50-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-50-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-peermem.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-50-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...
libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-compute-utils-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56+1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56+1) wird eingerichtet ...
linux-image-nvidia-5.15.0-50-generic: constructing .ko files
nvidia-drm.ko: OK
nvidia-modeset.ko: OK
nvidia-peermem.ko: OK
nvidia-uvm.ko: OK
nvidia.ko: OK
linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04 (5.15.0-50.56+1) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-driver-515 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
Trigger für man-db (2.10.2-1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) werden verarbeitet ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
Trigger für linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56) werden verarbeitet ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-50-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-50-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-48-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
Log ended: 2022-10-14  10:38:11

Log started: 2022-10-14  10:38:30
(Lese Datenbank ... 
(Lese Datenbank ... 5%
(Lese Datenbank ... 10%
(Lese Datenbank ... 15%
(Lese Datenbank ... 20%
(Lese Datenbank ... 25%
(Lese Datenbank ... 30%
(Lese Datenbank ... 35%
(Lese Datenbank ... 40%
(Lese Datenbank ... 45%
(Lese Datenbank ... 50%
(Lese Datenbank ... 55%
(Lese Datenbank ... 60%
(Lese Datenbank ... 65%
(Lese Datenbank ... 70%
(Lese Datenbank ... 75%
(Lese Datenbank ... 80%
(Lese Datenbank ... 85%
(Lese Datenbank ... 90%
(Lese Datenbank ... 95%
(Lese Datenbank ... 100%
(Lese Datenbank ... 319808 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Entfernen von appmenu-gtk-module-common (0.7.6-2) ...
Entfernen von libappmenu-gtk3-parser0:amd64 (0.7.6-2) ...
Entfernen von libc-ares2:amd64 (1.18.1-1build1) ...
Entfernen von libgoocanvas-2.0-9:amd64 (2.0.4-1build1) ...
Entfernen von libgoocanvas-2.0-common (2.0.4-1build1) ...
Entfernen von libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1) ...
Trigger für libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.72.1-1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.1-1) werden verarbeitet ...
(Lese Datenbank ... 
(Lese Datenbank ... 5%
(Lese Datenbank ... 10%
(Lese Datenbank ... 15%
(Lese Datenbank ... 20%
(Lese Datenbank ... 25%
(Lese Datenbank ... 30%
(Lese Datenbank ... 35%
(Lese Datenbank ... 40%
(Lese Datenbank ... 45%
(Lese Datenbank ... 50%
(Lese Datenbank ... 55%
(Lese Datenbank ... 60%
(Lese Datenbank ... 65%
(Lese Datenbank ... 70%
(Lese Datenbank ... 75%
(Lese Datenbank ... 80%
(Lese Datenbank ... 85%
(Lese Datenbank ... 90%
(Lese Datenbank ... 95%
(Lese Datenbank ... 100%
(Lese Datenbank ... 319706 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Löschen der Konfigurationsdateien von appmenu-gtk-module-common (0.7.6-2) ...
Log ended: 2022-10-14  10:38:31
```

`apt.log`:

```
Log time: 2022-10-14 10:35:52.456720
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-48-generic:amd64 < 5.15.0-48.54 @ii mK Ib >
Broken linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-48-generic:amd64 Hängt ab von on nvidia-kernel-common-515:amd64 < 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 -> 515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umU > (<= 515.65.01-1)
  Considering nvidia-kernel-common-515:amd64 19 as a solution to linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-48-generic:amd64 0
  Removing linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-48-generic:amd64 rather than change nvidia-kernel-common-515:amd64
Done
Log time: 2022-10-14 10:38:12.839733
  MarkPurge libgoocanvas-2.0-common:amd64 < 2.0.4-1build1 @ii gK > FU=1
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) libgoocanvas-2.0-9:amd64 < 2.0.4-1build1 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libgoocanvas-2.0-9:amd64 Hängt ab von on libgoocanvas-2.0-common:amd64 < 2.0.4-1build1 @ii pgP > (= 2.0.4-1build1)
  Considering libgoocanvas-2.0-common:amd64 10000 as a solution to libgoocanvas-2.0-9:amd64 0
  Removing libgoocanvas-2.0-9:amd64 rather than change libgoocanvas-2.0-common:amd64
  MarkDelete libgoocanvas-2.0-9:amd64 < 2.0.4-1build1 @ii gK Ib > FU=0
Done
  MarkPurge appmenu-gtk-module-common:amd64 < 0.7.6-2 @ii gK > FU=1
  MarkPurge libc-ares2:amd64 < 1.18.1-1build1 @ii gK > FU=1
  MarkPurge libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:amd64 < 2.1.27+dfsg2-3ubuntu1 @ii gK > FU=1
  MarkPurge libgoocanvas-2.0-9:amd64 < 2.0.4-1build1 @ii gP > FU=1
  MarkPurge libappmenu-gtk3-parser0:amd64 < 0.7.6-2 @ii gK > FU=1
```

Comment: modinfo --> not found:  looks like the driver for that version of the kernel failed to build.  Attempting to rebuild it may either fix the problem or uncover the real error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed the Ubuntu update routine. A dialogue popped up announcing a partial system update (not sure about tje terminology).  Software was installed and removed and after the reboot sound was missing and the NVIDIA driver (which had remained unchanged for months) did not work anymore.

Comment: It sounds like your update didn't finish or a part of it was aborted.  You need to rerun the driver install or look for log files.

Comment: The update routine ended without error. Re-installing the driver did not help. Could you specify which logs are necessary? Thx

Comment: The standard location for the 515 nvidia.ko module for the ...50 kernel is: /usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-515  How did you originally install the nvidia module and when you reinstalled, did you clean out every package with "nvidia" in the name?   Standard repos are all you need for the 515.76 driver.

Comment: Originally I installed the NVIDIA driver from the graphical frontend "additional drivers" in June. After the system update on Oct. 14th (I posted the logs in seperate answers) the screen remained black. Bootiing th .48 kernel resulted in a working environment. Then I tried to reinstall from the same frontend. I have not cleaned out anything. Maybe that messed up everything even more but the fact remains that the system update on Oct 14th did not work and in the apt.log "broken count: 1" can be found as you can see in the post below. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The content of usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-50-generic/kernel/nvidia-515   is: bits           nvidia.ko          nvidia-peermem.ko
nvidia-drm.ko  nvidia-modeset.ko  nvidia-uvm.ko

Comment: Updates spew out so many messages, it would not be hard to miss it failing to build a driver, and as this is a non-fatal error (for the update), it won't abort the update or show up as an error at the end.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Did you asked the question on the nvidia forum by chance?

Comment: No. This is my first attempt to find a solution. Which forum do you refer to? Ist there a discussion on this issue?

Comment: Looks like I am facing an identical issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436629/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-rtx-3060ti-failed-to-allocate-nvkmskapidevice

Comment: not sure if it really helped but it removed the ERROR sudo ln /usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue after reboot (1050 Ti) with blank screen an just a blinking cursor afterwards. This is what fixed it for me:

- Go to a terminal with [CTRL]+[ALT]+[F2], when systemd keeps switching back to blinking cursor during the process press [CTRL]+[ALT]+[F2] again
- log in with your system with your user on the terminal
- `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` (this finishes most of the broken unattented upgrade, but not the nvidia driver)
- `sudo apt install --upgrade linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic` (this fixed the missing nvidia kernel module for me)
- `sudo reboot`

It seems an unattended upgrade broke my system, this is what my /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log for the last updated looked like:

```
2022-10-17 07:28:48,250 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2022-10-17 07:28:48,250 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security
2022-10-17 07:28:48,250 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2022-10-17 07:28:48,250 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2022-10-17 07:29:05,790 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: libnvidia-common-515 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev unzip
2022-10-17 07:29:05,790 INFO Writing dpkg log to /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
2022-10-17 07:29:52,028 INFO All upgrades installed
2022-10-17 07:30:10,913 INFO Packages that were successfully auto-removed: linux-headers-5.15.0-47 linux-headers-5.15.0-47-generic linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-47-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-47-generic linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-47-generic linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-47-generic linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-47-generic
2022-10-17 07:30:10,913 INFO Packages that are kept back: 
2022-10-17 07:30:11,064 INFO Package libnvidia-cfg1-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,066 INFO Package libnvidia-compute-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,067 INFO Package libnvidia-compute-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,069 INFO Package libnvidia-decode-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,070 INFO Package libnvidia-decode-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,072 INFO Package libnvidia-encode-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,073 INFO Package libnvidia-encode-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,075 INFO Package libnvidia-extra-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,076 INFO Package libnvidia-fbc1-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,078 INFO Package libnvidia-fbc1-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,080 INFO Package libnvidia-gl-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,082 INFO Package libnvidia-gl-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2022-10-17 07:30:11,118 INFO Package linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not change anything. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and I have the same "kept back" lines in my `var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`

Comment: This worked for me on a 22.04 ubuntu laptop except I substituted 525 as time has moved on.  That fixed the "kept back" error and I plan to test this on my desktop and confirm it fixes the second screen issue not working (or doesn't fix it) later

Answer (score 1):

While ubuntu now have the 515-open driver "recommended", for what it's worth, the nvidia open kernel modules are considered by nvidia to be "Alpha quality" for consumer and workstation GPUs.

See https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules

I would recommend using the 510 release until the open source driver matures.

Comment: what about the `515-server` driver. Can I use on a regular PC?

Comment: well, rebooted my pc and the 515-server driver has apparently fixed my problem. No `NvKmsKapiDevice` problem on boot and the dual screen works fine. Referring to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436629/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-rtx-3060ti-failed-to-allocate-nvkmskapidevice

Comment: The NVIDIA 510 graphics driver works fine. Thanks for all the help in this great community

Comment: THANK YOU. Somehow I got switched from the 515 driver to the 525-open driver and my system completely freaked out. An hour later, I find your comment and that fixed it right away.