# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, RTX 3060Ti, Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am facing a strange problem out of nowhere. I turned off the PC fine with latest Nvidia proprietary drivers installed yesterday. Booting this morning, I noticed that one of my two monitors was not working and noticed these error messages on reboot

```
[ 7.348261] kernel: [drm:nv_drm_load [nvidia_drm]] ERROR [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice
[ 7.348371] kernel: [drm:nv_drm_probe_devices [nvidia_drm]] ERROR [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000800] Failed to register device
```

Thinking some driver crash, I uninstalled proprietary driver using TTY and installed default driver but I am still seeing same DRM error on boot. I am unable to install proper drivers (all Nvidia drivers are grayed out in Ubuntu software “additional drivers”) so unable to use my dual monitor setup. I have a dual boot setup with Windows and it works fine with Windows. I have disabled Virtualization in BIOS, no effect.

The system is unstable as well. Sometimes after login, I get a black screen but the PC is working in the background because I hit the correct keyboard shortcuts, I'm able to shutdown the PC. Sometimes it won't go black and work flawlessly (it has been working with one monitor for last 12hrs)

`uname -r` outputs `5.15.0-52-generic`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Update: I went ahead and using TTY I installed the `nvidia-driver-515-server` drivers. I have not restart the PC since though. How do I troubleshoot this issue

Comment: I think my issue is identical to this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435759/nvidia-driver-is-no-longer-working-with-new-kernel?rq=1

Comment: nvidia-bug-report log can be found here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/uploads/short-url/qs6ZKixvIp7uqyT41B6Np0nkSRK.gz

Answer (score 4):

Try rolling back your driver.  I had the same error message with RTX2070 on driver version 515 and 520.

I installed driver 510, which works fine for me.

Comment: LUO / NotTheDr01ds fixed for me. Many thanks. Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I have a rtx 3060ti also. had to install the legacy driver:

```
sudo apt remove nvidia* && \
sudo apt autoremove && \
sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-470
```

remember to reboot then try `nvidia-smi`.
if gpu device still not found look at kernel log for clues

`cat /var/log/kern.log`

related links

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/failed-to-allocate-nvkmskapidevice-in-hiveos/213998

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/geforce-rtx-3060-not-working-with-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa/190228

Comment: Thanks for this. Ubuntu's "Additional Drivers" claimed that I was using a driver that wasn't installed. `nvidia-bug-report.sh` reported the error in this issue, which really was, "What are you talking about nothing is installed." I should have checked that first.