# Nvidia Black Screen Usb-C on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, external-monitor, usb-c

**Problem:**

- I have a **Laptop** with **Nvidia** on **Ubuntu 22.04.02**.
- Suddenly for a month ago, the USB-C External monitor is just Black Screen - No errors, no nothing, just black screen.
- The monitor says (NO SIGNAL), when plugging in the USB-C.
- It's still the same installed version of Ubuntu, as I had some months ago. I have only run regular updates.

**What works:**

- I dual-boot into Windows and it works perfectly.

**What have I tried:**

- All these Nvidia Drivers:
  [image]

**Overview:**

- Lenovo 16p Laptop, Amd cpu
- LG monitor usb-c
- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Linux kernel 5.15.0-40-generic

**About:**

- It has a AMD GPU in the CPU
- It has a dedicated Nvidia (inside the laptop)
- Both GPU's are what the laptop comes with out of the box.

[image]

It was working a few months ago. Same machine, same install. Now it does not work.

**What can I do?** (Please HELP : )

---

**sudo lshw -C display**

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=2560x1600 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1600
       resources: iomemory:80-7f iomemory:a0-9f memory:fc000000-fcffffff memory:800000000-9ffffffff memory:a00000000-a01ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:fd080000-fd0fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cezanne
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=2560,1600
       resources: iomemory:a0-9f iomemory:a0-9f irq:55 memory:a10000000-a1fffffff memory:a20000000-a201fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:fd400000-fd47ffff
```

---

**nvidia-settings** command output:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


(nvidia-settings:9744): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:02:48.986: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:9744): CRITICAL **: 21:02:48.987: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. This file should have been installed along
       with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application profiles will continue to
       work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible
       values and descriptions.

** Message: 21:02:49.016: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 21:02:49.016: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I read the post here:
[Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, RTX 3060Ti, Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436629/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-rtx-3060ti-failed-to-allocate-nvkmskapidevice)

1. I did:

```
sudo apt remove nvidia* && \
sudo apt autoremove && \
sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-470
```

2.I had to go into Nvidia X Server Settings

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings
nvidia-settings
```

3. go to PRIME and select Full Power. Reboot, at the login screen the external monitor will show ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop, installing Synaptic DisplayLink USB Graphics driver solved the issue for me:
https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu

Comment: can you write the full name of the nvidia driver you have selected?

Comment: @MartinAndersen currently on the latest proprietary one, `nvidia-driver-535`

Comment: It did not work for me :-/